# initial click handler has empty state, second click has correct state react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react state and function that concats some data from a event click that event fires but the state is empty until the second click. Not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

```
const [skuObject, setSkuObject] = useState({ id: null, quantity: null })

  const [cartAdds, setCartAdds] = useState([])
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("")

  const handleCart = (id, quantity) => {
    console.log("test")
    setCartAdds(cartAdds => [...cartAdds, query])
    setQuery({ id: id, quantity })
    console.log(cartAdds)
  }
```

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.handleCart(id, quantity)}>
 Add to Cart
</button>
```

Comment: the value of `cartAdds` doesn't change in the context of `handleCart` until the component re-renders. you should use `useEffect` to detect changes in state and handle the change there.

Comment: `query` is `""` the first time you call `setCartAdds()`

Comment: @Anthony is there a way to make the object show up the first time instead of the `" "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), **State Updates May Be Asynchronous**.

This is to allow the state updates to be batched together for better performance.

This means that the setState is working, but the `console.log` is firing off before the state actually changes.

Put the logging in the render function, or in a `useEffect` and you will see it fire correctly